# AngularJS - binding a function to an isolate scope via '&', not firing on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I have a parent directive with a controller that sets a method on $scope.

Then, in the child directive, I try to require that scope method via `&`.

However, the `ng-click` inside the child directive will not fire with the parent scope function. Am I doing this wrong?

**Parent directive (where method is defined)**

```
app.directive('ParentDirective', [
    '$http',
    function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: '' +
                '<div child-directive ' +
                    'list="list" ' +
                '/>' +
            '',
            controller: function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.setSelected = function (selector) {
                    console.log('hit!', selector);
                }

                $scope.list = [];

            },
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {}
        };
    }
]);
```

**Child Directive (try to call parent method on ng-click, but not working)**

```
app.directive('childDirective', [

        '$window',
        function($window) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: {
                    setSelected: '&',
                    list: '=',
                },
                template: '' +
                    '<ul>' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="person in list" ng-click="setSelected(person)">{{person.uri}}</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '',
                link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Am I passing `$scope.setSelected()` incorrectly from the parent to the child directive?

**EDIT**: So I changed the parent template to assign the function like so:
            template: '' +
                '' +
            '',

this will now trigger the function, but the argument does not get passed from the child directive. How can I get the child directive to pass an argument into the parent directive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParentDirective has typo should be: parentDirective

in the parentDirective template you should pass the function 'list="list" ' + 'set-selected="setSelected(person)"'

try this:

html:

```
<parent-directive ></parent-directive>
```

js:

```
app.directive('parentDirective', [
    '$http',
    function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: '' +
                '<div child-directive ' +
                    'list="list" ' + 'set-selected="setSelected(person)"'+
                '/>' +
            '',
            controller: function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.setSelected = function (selector) {
                    console.log('hit!', selector);
                }

                $scope.list = [];

            },
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {}
        };
    }
])
  app.directive('childDirective', [

        '$window',
        function($window) {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: {
                    setSelected: '&',
                    list: '=',
                },
                template: '' +
                    '<ul>' +
                        '<li ng-repeat="person in list" ng-click="setSelected({person:person})">{{person.uri}}</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '',
                link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KUWZ9bYbhnbumFwIgcIX?p=preview

Comment: argument is still undefined for me, but I know there is data in the ng-repeat because I see the `{{person.uri}}`... but when I try to log out selector in `$scope.setSelected()` it's undefined.

Comment: ahh I was using a different argument name in `set-selected="setSelected(person)` so it was undefined. when I changed it to `person` it worked. Thanks!

Comment: sure @Prefix glad it helped